# Default value on nz-autocomplete when using reactive form

Tags: autocomplete, ng-zorro-antd

I am trying to set a default value on nz-autocmplete when in edit mode on my form. However the input is showing as [object Object]. It only works as expected when you select it manualy from the nz-autocmplete dropdown.

I am using:

- Angular: 9.1
- ng-zorro-antd: 8.5.2

That's the input code snippet:

```
<nz-form-item>
 <nz-form-label nzRequired [nzSm]="10" [nzXs]="24" nzFor="mainClient">
   <span class="intern-detail">Hlavny klient</span>
 </nz-form-label>
 <nz-form-control [nzSm]="14" [nzXs]="24" [nzErrorTip]="userErrorTpl">
  <nz-input-group [nzSuffix]="addNewClientButton">
   <input formControlName="mainClient" nz-input [nzAutocomplete]="clientAutocomplete"/>
  </nz-input-group>
 </nz-form-control>
</nz-form-item>
```

That's the autocomplete code snippet:

```
<nz-autocomplete #clientAutocomplete [compareWith]="compareFun">
  <nz-auto-option *ngFor="let client of filteredClients" [nzValue]="client" [nzLabel]="client.name">
      <p class="small-height bold">{{ client.name }}</p>
      <p class="small-height tiny-font">{{ client.email }}</p>
      <p class="small-height tiny-font">{{ client.phoneNumber1 }}</p>
  </nz-auto-option>
</nz-autocomplete>
```

Thank you for any ideas how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the reason for my issue is that I was using a dynamic data source.

Since my dynamic data source was empty on initialization nz-autocomplete had nothing to compare to so it returns `[Object, Object]`

So what I had to do was code the data that I put as the value for the control field as the same data in my dynamic data on initialization.

For you, that would mean that `filteredClients` would have to have the same initial data that you set for the `mainClient` control field value.